# Excluding null values when building JSON objects in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to build a json object where only non-null values are included.  For example:

```
SELECT 
id,
jsonb_build_object(
'price', price,
'item_returned_date', item_returned_date
) as data
from table
```

would return the following if the first row had null item_returned date:

```
id     |     data
1            {"price": 50}
2            {"price": 100, "item_returned_date: "2022-10-01"}
```

Is this possible without writing a complex function?

Comment: does it reall matter that the date is empty, a json should always be equal for all rows

Comment: `jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object(...))`?

Comment: What counts as complex?

Comment: @nbk "a json should always be equal for all rows" - definitely not true. One of the key benefits of schema-less data like JSON is that you don't have to maintain a specific schema across records.

Comment: @Yarin JSOn is horrible to maitain, when ypu select you have ideally alle structures complete with or without data, schema less is for quieries a false concept